# Managing View Dependencies

Tags: postgresql, dependencies

I am using PostgreSQL and I am adding a single column to a view.  Unfortunately, I will have to drop and recreate that view as well as the 9 other views that are dependant on the view.

What strategies or tools are good to manage doing this type of database management?

Comment: Use a schema management tool like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: Yep, or just keep your view definitions as SQL scripts in git